# React Toast When navigate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-fullstack

```js
try{
     const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
     console.log(user);
     navigate('/login');
     toast.success('Registered Successfully');
                
    }
    catch(error){
       console.log(error);
    
    }
```

I'm trying to display toast message after navigates to login page. But I didn't getting any toast notification after redirecting to login page. Plase help me to slove this

Comment: Maybe you can add the `toast.success` inside login.html page. If you're using React, put the `toast.success` function inside `useEffect()` with an empty dependency array inside Login component.

Answer (score 2):

your code doesn't reach `toast.success` because your app navigates to /login.

you need to fire `toast` from login page after passing a **query param**.

```
navigate('/login?success=true');
```

in login page:

```
const query = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParam = query.get("success");

if(myParam === 'true'){
   toast.success('Registered Successfully');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to add some sort of delay before `navigating` to other `screen`  otherwise the process would be so fast that user won't be able to see the `toast`. Try doing like this:

```
try {
     const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
     console.log(user);
     toast.success('Registered Successfully');
     
     setTimeout(() => {
       navigate('/login');
     }, 1000);                    
  }
  catch(error){
       console.log(error);      
  }
```