# React - Toast message not working properly

Tags: reactjs, toast

I am trying to implement a login check. I want to check if the user is logged in before he/she can view the page. If not, then redirect the user to the login page. When the user is redirected to the login page, I want to display a toast message - "Login Required". Here is what I have done -

```
import Layout from "../../../Component/Layout/Layout";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../../../Context/AuthContext";
import { toast } from 'react-hot-toast';

function Dashboard() {
    const {isLoggedIn, userId, userType, login, logout} = useAuth();
    
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
        toast.error("Login Required");
        return <Navigate to="/login" />;
    }
    
    return (
        <Layout>
            <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default Dashboard;
```

useAuth() is a custom hook that I have created.

The issue is that, when I am redirected, the toast message is not being shown. It is only visible when it is about to disappear. How do I fix this?

Edit 1: I read that adding a timeout before navigating would help. I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75920012/react-toast-when-navigate

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this will resolve your issue

```
import Layout from "../../../Component/Layout/Layout";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../../../Context/AuthContext";
import { toast } from 'react-hot-toast';

function Dashboard() {
    const { isLoggedIn } = useAuth();

    if (!isLoggedIn) {
        toast.error("Login Required");

        setTimeout(() => {
            return <Navigate to="/login" />;
        }, 1000);
    }

    return (
        <Layout>
            <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: I have tried this. I did not work. I issue still persisted.